# How can I get facebook albums with images from users

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

I am creating a facebook app and i want to display the users albums with the cover image, i have tried with code #1 but it is really really slow as i make a facebook api call in the foreach which makes my app take forever, so I am looking for another way to make the api call just once and get all the info, so i tried with FQL multi query (code#2) but now i have a problem because if the album has no image it won´t return nothing, so please check my codes and if you have any idea how i can do this i will greatly appreciate it

```
code#1
$albums = $facebook->api('/me/albums?limit=0&fields=id,name,count,cover_photo');
foreach($albums['data'] as $album)
                {
                // get all photos for album
                $photos = $facebook->api("/{$album['id']}/?fields=picture,name,count");
                $foto = $photos['picture'];
                $nombre = $album['name'];

                $id = $album['id'];
                $count = $album['count'];
                $cover_photo = $album['cover_photo'];
                $nombre = $nombre." (".$count.")";


                echo "<li> <a href=\"album.php?numero_album=$id&nombre_album=$nombre \" title=\"$nombre\"><img src=\"https://graph.facebook.com/{$cover_photo}/\" alt=\"$nombre\" /> </a> </li>";
                }


code#2
$multiQuery = '{
  "albumes":"SELECT name,cover_pid,object_id,size FROM album WHERE owner=me()",
  "portadas":"SELECT src_big FROM photo WHERE pid IN (SELECT cover_pid FROM #albumes)"
        }';

        $param = array(       
     'method' => 'fql.multiquery',       
     'queries' => $multiQuery,       
     'callback' => '');       
        $queryresults = $facebook->api($param);

                foreach($queryresults[0]['fql_result_set'] as $album)
                {
                $nombre = $album['name'];
                $id = $album['object_id'];
                $count = $album['size'];
                $nombre = $nombre." (".$count.")";


                echo "<li> <a href=\"album.php?numero_album=$id&nombre_album=$nombre \" title=\"$nombre\"><img src=\"https://graph.facebook.com/{$cover_photo}/\" alt=\"$nombre\" /> </a> </li>";
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

> so i tried with FQL multi query (code#2) but now i have a problem because if the album has no image it won´t return nothing

Can’t really see your problem there. If I try your queries using the Graph API explorer, it gives me all my albums, and a cover photo for each one that has one. (So that’s 4 albums and 3 photos for me.)

If you’re having trouble to tell which photo is from which album – then just include the `aid` field in both queries.

> it is really really slow as i make a facebook api call in the foreach which makes my app take forever

Of course it does, because each API call means another HTTP request, and those are *slow*.

If the FQL method doesn’t give you what you want, then make your API requests into [batch requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/) – that reduces the number of HTTP requests, and therefor should speed things up quite well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! but how can i display the images of each album with the name of the album? sorry if this is a really stupid question but i am learning the Facebook API @CBroe